# Left Join query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables.

```
Table 1:
ID     Name      Age       PhoneNumber 
12     Joe       25        873827382
23     Bob       28        928398233
34     Jane      23        237828883


Table 2:
ID     Agent       QuantitySold    
12      A1            100
23      B1            300
12      C1            600
34      A2            400
34      B1            800
23      B2            900
```

I want to show all the details of the employees who have never sold a quantity not equal to 800.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Age, a.PhoneNumber
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.ID= b.ID AND b.quantity <> 800
```

I want a result set that doesn't have ID 34 in it. But I cant seem to achieve that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked.

```
SELECT a.ID
     , a.Name
     , a.Age
     , a.PhoneNumber
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table2 QuantitySold = 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` without any of the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT a.ID
     , a.Name
     , a.Age
     , a.PhoneNumber
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID = a.ID AND QuantitySold = 800)
```

By the way, the column name is `QuantitySold`, not `quantity`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/452fa/1)

Comment: It is better not to post a answer which is already present. Keep the SO `clean`. `Exists`to `Not exists` is not a big change here

Comment: @ NoDisplayName : I am not a big fan of such behavior either and I would probably delete my answer in any other situation, but as you can see, I was putting together a fiddle while you were posting an answer, so it took a while to edit my question, _no offense_.

Comment: @notulysses - I stand corrected. Mine is actually wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `Left Join` to `Inner Join`.

`Left Join` will bring all the rows from `table1` even though he never made a `sales`. I will do this using `Exists`.

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Name,
       a.Age,
       a.PhoneNumber
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 b
               WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
                      AND b.quantity <> 800)
```

Comment: This didn't work. I still have the record with ID 34 in my result set

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using Left Join. Use inner join rather. Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Age, a.PhoneNumber, SUM(b.quantity)
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b
ON a.ID= b.ID 
GROUP BY b.Agent
HAVING SUM(b.quantity) <> 800
```